# How to allow Google Chrome to access your microphone forever on local server?

Tags: node.js, https, server, localhost

I've created my LocalHost using **Node.js** to test and debug my javascript project.
I'm Using Chrome.
On HTTPS server I need to click allow using mic just the first time, but in my localhost, I need to click on allow pup op each time my project calls microphone.

How do I allow access to my microphone on my localhost once?

If there is not a way to achieve that do you know any free https hosting fo testing purposes...

Answer (score 0):

You need a secure connection in order for Chrome to remember your permission preference. You should be able to create a self-signed cert (the instructions differ based on the OS) so that you can actually visit localhost securely, once you've done that your microphone will be accessible between page loads.

Comment: Is there any for windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 what? There are a lot of options for server software out there, but the short answer is yes